# What to do about out-of-date meta questions?

Tags: discussion, meta

For [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11187/are-the-language-elements-in-snow-crash-supported-by-science#comment20384_11187), I'd like to provide a link to the meta discussion about "is X on topic", so that the (reasonably new) user gets introduced to meta and gets and understanding of why these questions are off-topic and can provide an opinion (answer/vote) if so desired.

The problem is that we have a meta question specifically about this: [Should questions about “Is X science fiction” be off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-questions-about-is-x-science-fiction-be-off-topic), but the highest voted answer (by far) says that these questions *should* be on-topic.

The reason that these made it into the FAQ's off-topic list was [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/362/108) to another very redundant question that became popular.

ISTM that it's confusing to have contradictory information like this, especially since the question *specifically* about this topic has the 'incorrect' answer voted highest.  We get rid of closed questions so that users don't think "this other question like this is ok", but if they actually go to the effort of looking on meta, they'll find the wrong information.

What can we do about this?  There's no "out of date" close vote reason.  Vote to close the original (clear, simple, direct, i.e. better) question as a duplicate of the other? Chase down the 10 people that down-voted this type of question to go vote on the original?  Vote to close as "too localised"?  Flag it for a moderator to deal with it? (What would the mod do?)  Put an ugly edit in the question that indicates that it's out of date?

Comment: Tony, for the reference, the most popular answer to that question was deleted, for seemingly unimportant reasons. I've undeleted the answer, so it should be helpful now, it's pretty clear that those questions are indeed considered off topic.

Comment: The first link is older than the second.  Couldn't we close the earlier question as being 'too localized'?  Looks like there's [a precedent](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1263/1027) for that.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto ah, I presume Dori deleted all her posts when she ceased being a StackExchange employee (her comment on Twitter indicated that it wasn't a pleasant parting).  The last time this came up that was probably her post too - tricky considering she was so active (especially with good meta answers) in the early days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to handle out-of-date posts (assuming they cannot be fixed and are of no further use) is to close them as [too localized] (in time). They are no longer useful to future visitors.