# Are questions about alternate history on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

... even when the device used to achieve timeline divergence didn't involve time travel and similar.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. As per [my reasoning on another thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/faq-what-is-and-what-isnt-considered-science-fiction/43#43), all SF (what if?) is on-topic, including alternate history.

(To put this thread in context, it was written at a time when the site was wavering between being limited to science fiction, or being about speculative fiction in general. Eventually [we decided that this site was about speculative fiction in general](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-fantasy-in-spec-for-this-site) — the name of the site is “science fiction & fantasy” because these are the most recognizable subgenres of SF.)

Comment: Yes its on Topic. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37/faq-what-is-and-what-isnt-considered-science-fiction gave a good example: "Star Wars (set a "long time ago", and therefore not in the future)" So it is an alternate history and surely its Science Fiction, isn't it ?!