# Would non-horror Speculative Fiction be on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Speculative fiction is usually defined as science fiction, fantasy and horror plus some odds and ends. scifi and fantasy are on-topic for this site, but horror is not. So would that odds and ends present in speculative fiction be on-topic here?

Answer (score 12):

[Earlier](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-is-and-what-isnt-considered-science-fiction/43#)¹, I proposed to define the topic of this site as **speculative fiction**, with the [ISFDB definition](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/index.php/ISFDB%3aPolicy#Definitions) as a starting point. So that includes [alternate history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/are-questions-about-alternate-history-on-or-off-topic) and, yes, horror. If “**what if?**” is a key element of the work, it's on-topic.

Hmm, we should work the words “speculative fiction” into the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq). We don't use it as the name of the site because the term is relatively little-known.

¹  <sub>Context note: when this site started, it was for science fiction only. This meta question was one of the steps on the road to broadening the topic.</sub>

Comment: I agree. All these topics should be on topic.

Comment: Let it be known to all!  The Triumvirate of Moderators officially agrees.  Send forth the runners!