# Why was this 'not an answer' flag disputed?

Tags: support, flagging, specific-answer, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67219/19561) as 'not an answer':

> No it's not Harry Potter but is supposed to look like him. What he summoned isn't explained or likely to explained.

It is comprised of a reply to a *comment* of mine, and a statement that the poster doesn't know the answer to the actual question asked by the OP.

The flag shows as 'disputed'. Why?

---

Edited to add that I'm fine with answers stating *there is no answer*, as long as they explain *why* there is no answer. I've accepted and upvoted such answers. But this one just seems to boil down to "I dunno and I don't think anyone knows".

Comment: Sure looks like Not an Answer to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an answer, it's just not a very good one.

> No it's not Harry Potter but is supposed to look like him. **What he summoned isn't explained or likely to explained.**

See also:

- [Usefulness of “Plot hole” answers/comments](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/957/usefulness-of-plot-hole-answers-comments)
- [How to comment on “There is no in-universe answer”/“plot hole” answers lacking any evidence?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/how-to-comment-on-there-is-no-in-universe-answer-plot-hole-answers-lacking-a)

Sometimes there *isn't* an answer. As discussed in previous meta discussions, we ideally want to encourage people to essentially show some work here and explain how they've decided that there is no good, solid answer - but the lack of doing so doesn't make it *not*-an-answer.

In this particular case, the comment reply regarding Harry Potter sort of confuses the issue. Remove that part, and it's just an answer of questionable usefulness, but an answer nonetheless.

> What he summoned isn't explained or likely to explained.