# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

If you have high rep (>10k), you can see this answer of mine: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170330/931

I didn't delete it. And, I have no idea why it was deleted. I guess it was found offensive.

The other posts on the same page either say or assume Hitler and Nazi Germany absolute evil and nobody found it offensive. When I put it with different perspective to show that Wizards might not see Hitler as most people see, everyone is finding it offensive. I don't think criticizing a defunct empire which killed over 100 million people and a leader who artificially created famine to kill over 4 million people and countless more should be considered offensive if criticizing Nazi Germany and Hitler aren't offensive.

Also, if someone doesn't like my answer, they are free to downvote it, but why does the answer need to be deleted?

And, if my answer is deleted, why aren't other posts containing more direct hate speech against Hitler and Nazi Germany deleted?

Comment: `why aren't other posts containing more direct hate speech against Hitler and Nazi Germany deleted?` Because no one has flagged them, you're welcome to flag answers as you see fit.

Comment: When you're asking on meta about a deleted post, it's usually a good idea to include the *text* of the post in your question, so that even users with <10k rep can express their opinions about it on meta.

Comment: "*The sad truth of the world is that the winners of the war and powerful nations always enforce their version of history on the world. If you look at the torture and murder stats, Nazi Germany and even the Mongol Empire would look like a kid in front of the British Empire. The British opposite of Hitler was also not a saint: 'Winston Churchill is no better than Adolf Hitler,' says Indian politician Dr Shashi Tharoor.
As the wizarding world wasn't brainwashed by Muggle political propaganda, Dumbledore didn't see Hitler as an absolute evil who terrorized innocents.*"

Comment: In what world is saying Hitler was evil offensive?  Again this reeks of a political statement and had no place no place on this site.

Comment: Are you asking why your answer that states 'Hitler wasn't all that bad' was closed?

Comment: @Möoz It doesn't say that; it says Churchill and the British empire were also bad. Why do people persist in misrepresenting this answer?

Comment: @Skooba In what world is saying other mass-murdering regimes such as the British empire were evil offensive?

Comment: @Rand I'm commenting on his lack of insight into his own facetious behaviour. He _knows_ he's crossing lines and is doing it on purpose, as he's likely to do, habitually. I'd give this answer a bit more credence if it was another user, but Sachin has shown time after time that he merely wants to poke the bear. Is it _technically_ an answer? Sure. But that doesn't bode very well for him at this point if that's all he's got to offer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Can I ask, why did you force-open the post then lock it? Why not lock it in its closed state (which the community seems to prefer)?

Comment: @Möoz There wouldn't be much point in locking a post while it's deleted and only a very small number of people can even see it. This way, everyone can see both the answer itself and the fact that there are some kind of meta-worthy issues about it. (Also, just because some high-rep community members are teaming up to delete a post they disagree with by a user they dislike doesn't mean that the post actually fails to answer the question or otherwise violates site policy.)

Comment: “And, if my answer is deleted, why aren’t other posts containing more direct hate speech against Hitler and Nazi Germany deleted?” I’m not necessarily agitating for the deletion of your answer, but I’m not sure you understand what “hate speech” is if you think proclaiming one’s dislike of Nazis counts. Your answer also contains some dubious moral equivalences and borderline apologism for the Holocaust.

Comment: I mean, what’s up with this? “As the wizarding world wasn’t brainwashed by Muggle political propaganda, Dumbledore didn’t see Hitler as an absolute evil who terrorized innocents.” Are you saying that Hitler didn’t terrorize innocents? Untrue and poor-quality at best.

Comment: @Adamant See the next line.

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - Eh, plausible deniability.

Comment: @Möoz - vote for the post. Not the user. If the answer is technically an answer, it's... you guessed it, **an answer**. Whether you disagree with the content or not - that's what those up and down arrows are for.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To that does not mean the answer can still be offensive and removed in same.

Comment: This answer was complete speculation for the half a sentence it bothered to address the question. It was a bad answer and you should feel bad.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The disputes about this question appear to have been resolved. There's a solid consensus that it should be removed (again).

Comment: @dvk `vote for the post. Not the user.` I generally _do_ - and in many cases, begrudgingly - however, this particular user has _earned_ my distrust. Besides, in this case he fails to separate himself from the post, why are we obliged to do the same?. Also re `that's what those up and down arrows are for` the post was locked before I got a chance to DV this, had it not been, I'd wager we'd find it somewhere deep within the Halls of Mandos by now.

Comment: @Möoz - if people stop deleting it i'm sure we can lobby it to be unlocked so people can vote properly

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - If it gets unlocked, it'll be deleted almost immediately. And rightly so. It'll get murdered with downvotes before that happens though.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To 10 total votes +2/-8 net -6.... what do you think "voting properly" is?

Comment: @Skooba - I don't have an opinion (that i'm gonna bother sharing publicly, at least :) but I suspect most people voting to delete are likely to be happier with -20 or whatnot.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Then why do site mechanics allow for deletion at -1? Why does a post have stick around just to obtain some random down-vote number?

Comment: @Skooba Because deletion isn't a "you said something I don't like" option. It's a "you didn't answer the question / posted something offensive" option. Luckily enough, this answer is both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've undeleted it.**

Although it expresses some political views which some other users might disagree with, it does provide a possible answer to the question being asked, and even offers evidence from both the real world and Potterverse canon to support it. It may not be the *correct* answer, or a *good* answer, but that's a matter of opinion and something for up/down votes to decide.

Answers shouldn't be deleted just for expressing views that some users disagree with. The [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) mentions that "Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed", but your post here *does* propose an answer to the question; whether or not you're right is irrelevant.

Again from the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> **When should I vote to delete an answer?**
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

If you simply disagree with an answer (or the political statement it implies), downvote and move on.

Comment: answers shouldn't _contain_ political views on this site. take that crap to politics.se. this site is for science fiction.take out the entire second paragraph and it's a decent answer.

Comment: @KutuluMike The second paragraph addresses the issue of why the wizarding world didn't take part in WWII for purely altruistic and apolitical reasons. Without that, one could say "sure, there's the ISoWS, but couldn't an exception be made for helping the Allies against Nazi Germany?"

Comment: The second paragraph is a _made up justification_ for why Dumbledore, in the OPs own imagination, _might not_ have thought Hitler was evil. For which there is no evidence given other than "some other people thought Churchill was evil too", which is a logical fallacy on top of everything else. (They're both allowed to be evil.) It also goes against all common sense about how a character who spent their entire lives living in Britain would see Hitler in the middle of The Blitz.

Comment: @KutuluMike That's a rather rude way of saying it's a *theory about the answer to the question*. You've also misread or misunderstood the answer, since (1) it doesn't say Hitler wasn't evil, only that Churchill and the British empire were **also** evil (thus, no logical fallacy), and (2) it points out that a character who spent their entire life living in Britain wouldn't necessarily be subject to Muggle propaganda; why should Dumbledore see the Blitz as worse than the bombing of Dresden, say?

Comment: the entire answer is a rather transparent way to trash-talk the British by reviving a question that was asked 9 months ago by providing an answer that included precisely 0% additional relevant information wrapped around a unnecessary political rant, posted by a user with a long and pathetic history of causing trouble just to be a jerk about it, so I feel no need to pretend not to be annoyed by it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I find the fact that he's using this question as a vehicle to air his (pretty offensive IMO) political views to be unsuitable, especially give the lack of any canon backup to justify it.

Comment: @KutuluMike If you support the British empire, downvote the answer for criticising it. If you dislike the user, keep that to yourself. None of this seems to be a reason for *deletion*. Why are you calling it a "rant", anyway? It's just expressing a political opinion - one which, by the way, can be supported with *facts* about the atrocities committed by the Allies - not abusing anyone or going on at great length.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - None of which is suitable to be aired on a site about science fiction and fantasy. If he wants to debate history, we have an entire stack for him to do so on.

Comment: @Randal'Thor it's a rant because it has nothing at all to do with the question or the answer. Whether the British Empire was evil or not is completely irrelevant to why a character with Dumbledore's power didn't try to stop _another_ evil person in history. You could ask why didn't he stop _both_ of them, but the OP is fully away that answer was already given. They were just looking for an excuse to tell us that the British Empire f---'d over India in case we didn't already know.

Comment: @Randal'Thor and there's is a _HUGE_ difference between disliking a user, and recognizing that a user has _repeatedly_ taken actions to disrupt the site _despite_ being routinely punished for it, and deciding that said user no longer qualifies for "assuming good faith" because they have proven decisively that they have none.

Comment: @KutuluMike **Vote for the post, not for the user.** Yes, if someone's past actions prove that they're not acting in good faith, different action may be taken against them than someone else ... but that kind of action is for mods to take against users, not for other users to take against posts.

Comment: @KutuluMike Also, maybe you should read the answer more carefully? It first explains why someone like Dumbledore wouldn't side with Britain against Hitler, THEN explains why he wouldn't stop both of them either. Every time you describe this answer, you say it's doing X and would be OK if it was doing Y instead, when it's *actually* doing Y.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That would be an amazing answer if it had an iota of a scrap of evidence to back it up. In the absence of that, we have to assume that the OP is projecting their own politics onto the situation. We could just as easily argue (using the same logic) that Dumbledore was a massive anti-Semite.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you're ignoring the key part of my comment: if you take out the anti-British rant there is no _NEW_ information in the answer. The Dark Lord posted a very thorough answer about the  International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy nine months ago. SS's answer merely takes that exact information, presents it less clearly, and tacks on "plus Churchill was also evil" onto it.

Comment: I whole heartedly disagree with the original answer,  that the answer was undeleted, and this meta answer.

Comment: For the record what I also noticed that the user posted their answer and then started a vote to close as POB. If the user felt the question was POB, why provide an answer that is surely just opinion then. If I have my time line messed let  me know, but this is what I noticed...

Comment: @Himarm On what grounds? That you disagree with its political views? That you dislike the poster? I haven't yet seen anyone provide a good reason for *deleting* this answer (as opposed to simply downvoting it, which is your good right).

Comment: Well so far meta consensus seems to want it to be deleted

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Um, because it contains uncited material that others may find offensive?

Comment: Uncited - nope; as mentioned before, it's cited both to the Potterverse (e.g. International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy) and to the real world (e.g. real leaders who thought Churchill was as bad as Hitler). Offensive - well, if you're a British imperialist, then yes, you might be offended by someone mentioning the British empire's atrocities, but they still have the right to mention them. What do you think of, say, [this Great Answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2612/31394) which calls real political leaders "evil monsters" and scoffs at western Stalinists?

Comment: @Himarm So it's OK to criticise mass murderers as long as it's "world agreed" to do so, and not OK if they won the last major war and therefore wrote the history books? If you think Dresden, Nagasaki, and so on were all perfectly justified, that doesn't give you the right to silence people who call out war crimes and mass murder by Allied/western powers. Also, **nobody is defending Hitler**, only saying that the other powers in WWII were also evil. Why is that so hard for people to understand?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That'd be nice, if that's what the answer really was. It's not. There are so many things wrong with it. 1) Probable trolling from a user with a long history of suspensions. 2) Complete speculation, with a side of ignoring canon. 3) Minimization of the Holocaust. Yes, it's there. The heavy implication that it's "propaganda" that leads us Muggles to consider Hitler as "terrorizing innocents," the pointed quote by a politician saying that Hitler wasn't much compared to Churchill....

Comment: @Rand'alThor - "What-about-ism" is a classic technique for minimizing atrocities, too. "Hitler did it, but what about Stalin?" There are many ways to measure atrocities: probably more people were killed throughout the whole history of British colonialism than during the Holocaust. But that's really only because Hitler didn't get the chance. Had he won, he would have followed a standard colonialist rulebook in many parts of the world, and he'd have been much worse than Britain. Britain was mainly motivated by greed. The Nazi Party was mainly motivated by an ideology of racial supremacy.

Comment: One need not ignore the bombing of Dresden, the atrocities of Hiroshima and Nagasaki, or the Bengal famine to recognize when these events are being employed in defense of Hitler.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in the *worst* picture of things, Churchill was an anti-Semitic, anti-Muslim, anti-Hindu leader whose occasional callous negligence exacerbated lethal conditions. This is no recommendation, but, by contrast, Hitler pursued a systematic, widespread, and deliberate policy of genocide of several different ethnic groups, a policy which he vigorously pressed through conquest, and was an individual whose later politics were founded essentially solely on Aryan supremacy. Hitler could hardly have allowed Jews, Roma, Slavs, and so forth to starve: he was too busy gassing them.

Comment: That the fact that you are trying to justify a political statement should be a red flag, the fact this political statement is trying minize the evil Hitler did (even if by calling others evil) is a second red flag, and the community response to the answer and this meta post should be the third. I am baffled by the your actions. Answers get deleted every day with out a peep. I I fail to see why this any different. I did not think moderators were supposed to force their will on the community.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66202/discussion-on-answer-by-rand-althor-why-was-my-answer-deleted).

Comment: @Himarm - meta consensus doesn't override SE policy (which is what dictates what is and isn't a deletable answer).

Comment: *Stop casting delete votes on this answer*. First, it certainly does answer the Meta question (even if you don’t like it). Trying to delete it isn’t a good use of reputation privileges. Second, it was posted by a moderator, so it will just get undeleted and locked. And then Shog might drop by and everyone will get suspended. Let’s do our best to Be Nice here.

Comment: @Randal'Thor `[Sachin is] only saying that the other powers in WWII were also evil.` To what end? Why is he doing that _here_? He surely hasn't shown us that that's what JKR or Dumbledore thought or believed in any shape or form.

Answer (score 18):

I marked your answer for deletion because you seem to be trying to make some sort of ham-fisted political point about Hitler and the British Empire rather than making a serious effort to answer the question asked.

You've offered no evidence that the wizarding world view the British Empire in this way and are basically using the question as a vehicle to spout your own views.

Note that rants are specifically deemed to be [off-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

> your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: Your link is about questions, not answers.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I would assume it would apply to both (unless you're saying rants are on-topic), actually I believe we've had a recent meta about it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - If they don't apply to both, I have some choice answers I'd like to make :-)

Comment: The political rant you are referring spans only two sentences. If you get focused on it, it doesn't mean I am running a political propaganda in disguise.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10412/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-on-a-rant-about-us-declined) seems to suggest rants are only on-topic when there is an answer buried in them, and even then when the community decides to delete it that's a final decision

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - Fair enough. Remove that bit of the answer (and offer some evidence, why not) and I'll vote to reopen.