# What is the process by which a specific already-discussed policy gets added to site FAQ?

Tags: discussion, site-faq

If there is an existing meta discussion with clear results, what are the requirements for it to be added to the site FAQ, both substance wise and procedure wise?

Should they be added as answers here: [What should our FAQ contain?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/what-should-our-faq-contain?rq=1) ?

Should a new meta question be raised (meta-meta?) asking if a given meta question should be in the FAQ?

Should the existing meta question be flagged for moderators?

Comment: Yes, add new answers to that question.

Comment: @Keen - and then...?

Comment: Umm, people vote on it?  And if there's consensus, changes are implemented.

Comment: @Keen - What are the thresholds for consensus? Most answers on that question are at 0 or 2, and it's a 2 year old question that many people may not re-read (not everyone orders by recent activity). (some of existing FAQs are also very lightly voted, to veer off tangent).

Comment: @Keen - Also, I don't mind this being closed as a dupe, but you should really update the original question with official procedure and rules. There was a reason I asked this one.