# Why is the The Handmaid's Tale on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I see that there are a few *The Handmaid's Tale* questions on this site.

I have only seen the TV-series, not read the book, and I may recall incorrectly, but I am not aware of any supernatural or fantasy elements in the series. Nor do I remember anything not readily explained by current real-world technology.

Granted, the world the story is set in is rather bizarre, but I am not sure if it has any straight up *fantasy* or *science fiction* elements?

Correct me if I am wrong, I may remember incorrectly.

Comment: _The Handmaid’s Tale_ is a classic example of speculative fiction which broadly speaking is what this site is all about.

Comment: Duplicate of [Are all utopias and dystopias on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12363/are-all-utopias-and-dystopias-on-topic)

Comment: It's set in an alternate (dystopian) future. How much more fantastical do you want it to be?

Comment: @Valorum I usually interpret "fantasy" to be something that is supernatural or not readily explained by modern day science, such as a ring making the bearer invisible, or a spell defying the laws of gravity, etc. I was not aware that this site had a different idea of "fantasy". Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Revetahw - Quite a lot of our questions are about *Speculative* Fiction rather than *Science* Fiction or Science *Fantasy* (or just plain *Fantasy* Fantasy). All seem to be pretty welcome, except for Spy-fi which we tend to lump in with the Action genre..

Comment: @Valorum I see. I had not noticed.

Comment: [Speculative fiction](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/538/31394) is technically the site scope, but Sci-Fi & Fantasy sounds cooler ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are kinda 2 parts to the answer.

First, as a general rule we consider a work SF if it was written that way, even if real-world science has caught up to (and passed) it.

Secondly, a work set in a future society based on extrapolation of a possible societal trend *is* inherently science fictional.  (Sociology is a science.)  Were that not the case, *1984* wouldn't be SF.  The same would be true of most post-nuclear-war stories, since in very few cases is the science more advanced than today's (frequently it has gone backwards) and it is simply the scenario itself that is being explored.