# Duplicate history tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [science-fiction-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-history) & [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) seem redundant; does anyone with sufficient rep to propose a synonym agree?

Comment: Is there a [tag:fantasy-history]?

Comment: @Keen No, nor should there be.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I propose to make [science-fiction-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-history) a synonym of [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of). I [don't want to have to distinguish between fantasy and science fiction](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-fantasy-in-spec-for-this-site/10#10) in tags. Some of the questions taggedd [science-fiction-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-history) are about fantasy already (e.g. [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18437/what-was-the-first-school-of-magic-mentioned-in-modern-fantasy-literature)).

Comment: please don't use that question as precedent - I picked the only available tag and quite possibly did so incorrectly. I do agree that more SF/F agnostic tags would be better to avoid the pointless "is X SciFi or Fantasy" discussions.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should rename [science-fiction-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-history) to [genre-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-history).  Leave [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) in place, but clean up those questions so they're properly tagged with [genre-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-history).  There are questions ([example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/what-is-the-difference-historically-between-unfinished-tales-and-the-history-o)) that are about a history of a specific work/universe that are about history, but not history of the genre in general.  I think [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) should be used for these.

Comment: Sounds like you’re re-purposing [tag:history-of] for history of a particular franchise (_e.g._, “When was _Firefly_ cancelled?” [tag:history-of] [tag:firefly]), and using [tag:genre-history] for general questions about, well, the genre’s history. (Or rather, the genres’ histories, for the several genres that are in the scope of this site.)